# Как в битриксе убрать левое меню у разделов, у которых нет дочерних элементов?

Tags: битрикс

Есть элемент главного меню Компания с такой структурой

Компания

---- Работники

-------- Отдел кадров

-------- Отдел разработки

Когда находимся на странице Работники, то выводится меню с 2 отделами, всё правильно. Но и при нахождении на странице Отдел кадров, тоже показывается меню с этими двумя отделами. Как можно убрать меню на конечных узлах, у которых нет дочерних элементов? Есть вариант с помещением в каждый конечный раздел помещать пустой .left.menu.php, но это не выглядит хорошим решением. Был вариант, что указывать ссылки в меню со слешем на конце или без него на что-то повлияет, но и это не помогло.

Так выглядит .left.menu.php у родительского раздела Работники

```
<?
$aMenuLinks = Array(
Array(
    "Отдел разработки", 
    "design-department/index.php", 
    Array(), 
    Array(), 
    "" 
),
Array(
    "Отдел кадров", 
    "hr-department",
    Array(), 
    Array(), 
    "" 
)
);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Тут либо пустой .left.menu.php либо в коде вызова компонента меню нужно прописать условие. Например:
`if(strpos(SITE_DIR, '/design-department/')){}`